# How to get a nativeElement [attributes] value in angular test?

Tags: angular, testing, angular-directive

There are not any problem to take attributes value in the following case:

```html
<object class="someClass" someAttribute="someValue"></object>
```

```js
const elem = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('.someClass')).nativeElement;
elem.getAttribute('someAttribute'); // result 'someValue'
```

But how to take attributes value in this case?

```html
<object class="someClass" [someAttribute]="someValue"></object>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `[attr.someAttribute]="someValue"` to bind a property to a custom attribute called `someAttribute`.

`[someAttribute]="someValue"` will not compile as Angular will be looking for an input or directive called `someAttribute`.

So your finished HTML should look like this:

```
<object [attr.someAttribute]="someValue"></object>
```